# Cant connect to local Redis cluster with Lettuce

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm running a Redis local cluster with Docker like this

```
docker run --env "IP=0.0.0.0" -p 7000-7007:7000-7007 -p 5000-5002:5000-5002 -p 6379:6379 grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.3
```

I can't send commands when connected via telnet like

`telnet localhost 7000`

Hoewever when trying to connect with the lettuce client with the following code

```
    RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.Builder.redis("localhost", 7000).build();
    RedisClusterClient client = RedisClusterClient.create(redisURI);
    StatefulRedisClusterConnection<String, String> connection = client.connect();
    RedisStringCommands sync = connection.sync();
    String value = (String) sync.get("key");
```

The following exception is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='localhost', port=7000]]
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:865)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:819)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:345)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connect(RedisClusterClient.java:320)
at com.foo.DeleteMe.main(DeleteMe.java:22)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to establish a connection to Redis Cluster
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.AsyncConnections.get(AsyncConnections.java:84)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:68)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.doLoadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:871)
at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:844)
... 4 more
Suppressed: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:7000
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:209)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:199)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score -2):

```
  <!-- The configuration of maven-jar-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>shadeall</shadedClassifierName>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>com.ly.dc.io.netty</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. At least not without an explanation of how this fixes the problem.